# Setting input value with javascript nullifies PHP post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I a have PHP form where I collect a bunch of values from text inputs, but for one input I have the input filled in via javascript (user selects a date from a calendar, that date then populates a text input). I've setup a simplified version of this:

```
<?php

$displayForm = true;

if ($_POST['submitFlag'] == 1) {
    // Form was submitted. Check for errors and submit.
    $displayForm = false;

    $installationTime = $_POST['installation-time'];

    // send e-mail notification
    $recipients = "test@test.com";

    $subject = "Test Email - Test Form Submission";

    $message = wordwrap('Someone has filled out the secure form on test.com. Here\'s what they had to say:

    Installation Time: ' . $installationTime .'

');

    $headers = "From: test@test.com";

    mail($recipients, $subject, $message, $headers);

    // Output thank you message

?>

<h2>Thank You!</h2>

<?php if($installationTime == NULL){echo 'test failed: value submitted was null.';}else{echo 'test passed: value submitted was not null.';} ?>

<p>Your form has been submitted. Thank you for your interest in test.com.</p>

<?php

}

if ($displayForm) {
// If form was not submitted or errors detected, display form.
?>

<div class="note"><span class="required">*</span> Click me to set value of input.</div>

<form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?state=submit">

<label for="installation-time" class="service-time">The time you have selected for installation is: <span class="required">*</span></label>

<input type="text" name="installation-time" id="installation-time" disabled value="<?php echo $_POST['installation-time']; ?>" />

<input type="hidden" name="submitFlag" id="submitFlag" value="1" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Sign-Up" />

</form>

<?php
    } // End of block displaying form if needed.
?>
```

And then in jQuery I do one of these:

```
$('.note').click(function(){
$('#installation-time').val('test string');
});
```

When I submit the form, the PHP variable that's supposed to collect that value is null. Every other input in the form works, and if I remove the javascript and manually enter the exact same text that I had set with JavaScript into the input it works as well.

The question really is why populating a field with javascript as opposed to manually typing the exact same string into a text input would break things. Again there are no errors and the input is populated correctly on the front end. Somehow posting the form just doesn't pick up on the value when it's set by javascript vs. typed manually. There has to be something really fundamental I'm missing here.

Any idea what's going on here? I've spent hours puzzling over this to no avail.

Update:
Code updated, test page:
http://dev.rocdesign.info/test/

Comment: Sounds like the form is losing the dynamic value because it posts to itself. When the page loads for the POST the calendar is not picked so the field is blank?

Comment: Check your submit routine for errors.

Comment: @Jeff, there's no errors that I can find.

Comment: @andrew-buchan, if I have an input and I type into it "sample value", and do the submit, it works. Isn't this identical to saying $('input').val('sample value')? Either way, at the point of submission, the input has the same value. I guess I can't understand why setting it with JS would change anything...

Comment: Use Fiddler or another tool and see if the request includes the form element

Comment: Actually your jQuery and pure JS are doing different things... Maybe just a typo in your post?

Comment: I was inconsistent between the two on the element being targeted if that's what you mean (corrected it). But I can get it working either way. Otherwise I'm not sure. All things being equal and error free, if I type a value into an input and hit submit the value is correctly saved/passed to a variable, but if I set the value in javascript/jquery (and it appears correctly on the front end, again no errors) and hit submit it's not recorded.

Comment: The information that you have provided is not enough. Your problem is in a place you have not written here, please give link.

Comment: @tD3rk - Can you please share the full JS code that alters the input and then submits?

Comment: I updated with full code and put a test page at: http://dev.rocdesign.info/test-input/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: can't post a disabled input. I actually tested that back in the beginning and must have missed that removing the "disabled" on the input made it work, so I mistakenly ruled it out and moved on.

Thanks for the responses everyone. And for anyone else with this problem: use a hidden input to post the value.

Comment: Some browsers will post it still... beware